# Aspstate SQL Server database mirroring high IO

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, iis, amazon-ec2

We are currently having issues with aspstate database mirroring as we have around 10,000 active users online 9-5 day to day and the aspstate db is so heavy on writing and passing this to the mirror that the mirror's drive is very high on IO and keeps causing both servers to be inaccessible due to the latency of writing the data on the mirror. We're using SQL Server 2012 standard so not in asynchronous mode.

We're running the SQL Server on Amazon EC2 instances with EBS backed volumes and 1000IOPS, in your views should this be enough? As we seem to have very smooth times where we've had over 15,000 users online and then other times where only 10,000 users online and we have issues with disk queue lengths on the mirror (backup server not the principle server.)

The principle can be writing to the `aspstate.mdf` files at 10-20mbps constant when the disk queue length goes up.

We're going to increase the IOPS to 2000 in the mean time as currently we've had to disable mirroring, however would you expect this and has anyone handled this sort of volume before?

Regards

Liam
[image: Resource monitor]
[image: Performance monitor]
[image: Cloudwatch]

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck with a high transaction workload like ASPState is not the data file but the transaction log.  In the case of synchronous mirroring, additional latency is introduced for both the network and synchronous commit at the mirror.  This latency will not be tolerable if you have a large number of APSState requests.  Keep in mind that unless specified otherwise with session state enabled, each ASP.NET page request will require 2 updates to a session state row. So if you have 10,000 active users clicking once every 15 seconds, that requires about 1,300 I/Os per second for transaction log writes alone on each database.

If you must have HA for session state, I suggest failover clustering to eliminate network latency.  You might also consider tuning session state by specifying the read only or none directive for pages that don't need session state.  Consider using an in-memory session state solution instead of the out-of-the box ASPSession state database if you need to support a large number of users.  Also remember that session state data is temporary so you can forgo durability.

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for the reply. The log file writes fine on the principle server and doesn't write at all on the mirror server (as expected) however the issue is the data file in this case as it's the Mirror server not principle server which has the disk queue length issue as the log from the principle is used to constantly write to the mdata file of the mirror. But what confuses me is how the principle log file can be written to as much as the data of the mirror (has to be identical to mirror) yet only the mirror struggles, when both have the same IOPS on both data and log partitions?

Comment: @Liam Wheldon, not sure what you mean by doesn't write at all to the mirror (secondary).  Log records are written before data on both principal and secondary.

Comment: Hi Dan,I've added screenshots to show how I believe that the mdf is written to directly on the mirror. Thank you for sticking with me on this :-)

Comment: When you modify data at the principal, pages are modified in primary memory, written to the primary log buffer, log record sent to secondary, secondary modifies data in memory, secondary writes log record to disk synchronously to commit, primary writes log record to disk synchronously to commit upon response from secondary.  Pages are written to disk asynchronously by the lazy writer and checkpoint process on both primary and secondary.  A non-zero queue length for data files is normal and expected.  I think we should continue this conversation via chat.  I'm off to work now.

Comment: @Liam Wheldon, please join this chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62016/aspstate